# node-gyp tries to build dependency even after removing it from package.json

Tags: json, node.js, npm-install, node-gyp

I'm new to node, but running into a strange problem. Let me outline my steps:

1. Install a project that has the `fabric` dependency, which in turn depends on an old package called `contextify`. This project also uses `node-gyp` to install add-ons.
2. Run `npm install`, which fails with:

```
contextify@0.1.15 install /path/to/project/node_modules/contextify
node-gyp rebuild

  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/contextify/src/contextify.o
....
../src/contextify.cc:150:16: error: no member named  'SetAccessCheckCallbacks' in 'v8::ObjectTemplate'
        otmpl->SetAccessCheckCallbacks(GlobalPropertyNamedAccessCheck,
        ~~~~~  ^
...
```

3. Googling `otmpl->SetAccessCheckCallbacks(GlobalPropertyNamedAccessCheck,` gives some links ([node-gyp](https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp/issues/809), [fabric](https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp/issues/809)) that make it clear that this is a known issue with node versions. I have node 7.4, and this requires node 6 or earlier.
4. I realize that `fabric` is not actually used by this project, so I remove the dependency from my `package.json`
5. I delete my `node_modules` folder, and run `npm install` again. Same error.

Now comes the weird part: `npm install` (which invokes `node-gyp rebuild`) keeps trying to build contextify, even though I can prove it's no longer a dependency of anything in the project!

What I tried:

- Deleting my node cache, as output by `npm config get cache` (i.e., `rm -rf ~/.npm`)
- Uninstalling and reinstalling `node-gyp`
- Trying to hunt down a place where this package might be lurking in some half-installed state, such as `/usr/local/lib/node_modules`

None of these seem to work. Any clue what I can do to stop `npm` and `node-gyp` from trying to install this package? I am willing to completely blow away my node/npm/node-gyp setup and reinstall from scratch, but not quite sure how to do that properly.

Comment: In case anyone comes across this, I sort of resolved the problem. I think the problem is that `node` was installed via Homebrew. My ultimate "solution" was to uninstall all versions of node from my machine. Reinstall nvm (not using brew) and install node 6.9.4 using nvm. Install node-gyp globally. Use this to build my project, at which point it *still* builds contextify, but successfully because it's node 6. Then I got sick of this problem and kept working, and eventually the package disappeared. Seems like a cacheing issue.

Comment: Hey @JeremyKun thanks for the tip. I got past the issue by reverting to node 6.10.2. BTW, had you tried blowing away the whole node_modules and starting over with a fresh npm install?

Comment: Yes, I tried this and it did not help.

Answer (score 0):

Try downgrading the node version to 6

```
npm install node@6
```

Comment: From review: this looks more like a comment, can you move it there?